# Python Manipulate and save XML without third-party libraries

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml in which I have to search for a tag and replace the value of tag with a new values. For example,

```
<tag-Name>oldName</tag-Name>
```

and replace `oldName` to `newName` like

```
<tag-Name>newName</tag-Name>
```

and save the xml.  How can I do that without using thirdparty lib like `BeautifulSoup`

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option from the standard lib is (I think) the [xml.etree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) package.

Assuming that your example tag occurs only once somewhere in the document:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
# or for a faster C implementation
# import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
elem = tree.find('//tag-Name') # finds the first occurrence of element tag-Name
elem.text = 'newName'
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Or if there are multiple occurrences of tag-Name, and you want to change them all if they have "oldName" as content:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
for elem in tree.findall('//tag-Name'):
    if elem.text == 'oldName':
        elem.text = 'newName'
# some output options for example
tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has 'builtin' libraries for working with xml. For this simple task I'd look into minidom. You can find the docs here:

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain, I mean, completely 100% positive that the string `<tag-Name>` will *never* appear inside that tag and the XML will always be formatted like that, you can always use good old string manipulation tricks like:

```
xmlstring = xmlstring.replace('<tag-Name>oldName</tag-Name>', '<tag-Name>newName</tag-Name>')
```

If the XML isn't always as conveniently formatted as `<tag>value</tag>`, you could write something like:

```
a = """<tag-Name>


oldName


    </tag-Name>"""

def replacetagvalue(xmlstring, tag, oldvalue, newvalue):
    start = 0
    while True:
        try:
            start = xmlstring.index('<%s>' % tag, start) + 2 + len(tag)
        except ValueError:
            break
        end = xmlstring.index('</%s>' % tag, start)
        value = xmlstring[start:end].strip()
        if value == oldvalue:
            xmlstring = xmlstring[:start] + newvalue + xmlstring[end:]
    return xmlstring

print replacetagvalue(a, 'tag-Name', 'oldName', 'newName')
```

Others have already mentioned `xml.dom.minidom` which is probably a better idea if you're not absolutely certain beyond any doubt that your XML will be so simple. If you can guarantee that, though, remember that XML is just a big chunk of text that you can manipulate as needed.

I use similar tricks in some production code where simple checks like `if "somevalue" in htmlpage` are much faster and more understandable than invoking BeautifulSoup, lxml, or other *ML libraries.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, which package has xmlstring?

Comment: `xmlstring` is the string holding the XML data you're editing.